# Sails js, how do we write inner join using populate

Tags: node.js, sails.js, sails-postgresql

Sails's populate works as Left join. I want to do as inner join,

Anybody help me how we can write inner join using populate without writing raw query. I am using MYSQL adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have for example two models user , contacts 
relation one-to-many 
 you try to  write something like :-

first models will like this :-

user.js

```
module.exports = {
  schema: true,
  tableName: 'userdata',
  attributes: {
    anyField: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: false,
      size: 56,
    },
    contacts: {
      collection: 'Contact',
      via: 'user'
    }

};
```

contact.js :-

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    name: {
      type: 'string'
    },
        mobile_number: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    user: {
      model: 'User'
    }
};
```

and you can get result of populate like this :-

```
User.find(user.id).populate('contacts').exec(function (err, user) {
  // this contains  user object  and populated by contacts 
     console.log(user[0].contacts);
});
```

you get result like :-

```
{
name:'tets',
contacts:[{
 'name':'test',
'mobile_number':'00000'
},
{
 'name':'test',
'mobile_number':'00000'
},
{
 'name':'test',
'mobile_number':'00000'
}]
}
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, Do you know how to work this when you have an existing DB? I have an open question here you may be able to answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37742970/waterline-js-joins-populate-with-existing-database

Comment: That's not an inner join but a left join. It will also return users which does not have any contact. As fas as I know inner join is currently not possible using waterline.js, which is the default sails.js ORM.